# How to run a script automatically in linux?

Tags: bash, scripts

I use linux command line and I'm a beginner with it.
I've created two files, `test.sh` and `test.log`.
the process is any output going to `test.log` and i get it successfully the output in `test.log`.
I want to run a script automatically every 5 seconds and write only if there is any change with the `.sh` file.

`test.sh` contains :

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ] ;
do
echo "" date and Time >> test.log
date +%x_r >> test.log
lsusb >> test.log

sleep 5;
done
```

**My question:** Is there any way to run it automatically and only append the new change in the file with the new date? for example if anyone insert USB device into my machine it will append it with the new date into the existing log file it.

Comment: This seems like an unnecessarily complicated way to do it. You should check the manpages for cron

Answer (score 1):

This should work, it stores the last output of `lsusb` in $lastoutput and appends if they're if not equal

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ] 
do
    currentoutput="$(lsusb)"
    if [ "$currentoutput" != "$lastoutput" ]
    then
        echo "" date and Time >> test.log
        date +%x_r >> test.log
        lastoutput="$(lsusb)"
        lsusb >> test.log
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Thanks , but in this way it will not save the new change in .log file ,, i try it and it's running in the terminal not in the .log file

Comment: Yes its in the terminal , but the result (new change) should go to .log file but does not .

Comment: @Ghassan does the user running the script have enough permissions to write in the test.log file? Could it be that maybe you created the file as root and is now running it as your regular user?

Comment: My apologies, I did not realize that the code doesn't work (I was typing on my phone and I wasn't able to test it). I fixed it now, it should work

Comment: @Ghassan can you try the new code?

Comment: No it's still not working proper , it repeat one command which is "line 11: $'Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub\nBus 002 Device 003 ........."

Comment: The square brackets around `true` *happen* to work, but don't do what you think. The idiomatic way to write an endless loop is simply `while true` without any decorations. The argument to `while` (and `if` and `until`) is a command whose success or failure is the condition for the control statement.

Comment: This runs `lsusb` twice, potentially with different output. The proper way to do this is probably `lastoutput=$(lsusb | tee -a test.log)` to assign the variable and append to the log file in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of always logging the whole output of `lsusb`, you could use `diff` to output the changes only.

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="test.log"
lsusbout_before=

while sleep 1; do
    lsusbout_now="$(lsusb)"
    diff=$(diff <(printf '%s\n' "$lsusbout_before") <(printf '%s\n' "$lsusbout_now"))
    if [ $? = 1 ]; then
        date | tee -a "$logfile"
        printf '%s\n' "$diff" | grep '^[<>]' | tee -a "$logfile"
        lsusbout_before="$lsusbout_now"
    fi
done
```

Whenever something is added, `diff` outputs:

```
> ...
```

if something is removed, the output is

```
< ...
```

e.g. when I attach my USB stick:

```
Fr 12. Apr 10:55:48 CEST 2019
> Bus 002 Device 014: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
```

---

This script makes use of `diff` error code `1` if the files differ.

- `<(command)` file descriptor: generates a file in memory with the output of `command` as input, similar to `$(command)`.
- `[ $? = 1 ]` check error code of last command (here: `diff`).
- `grep '^[<>]'` is to suppress additional output of `diff` like position of changes which is irrelevant for us.

Answer (score -1):

You have to:

- put your file in `/etc/init.d` directory
- make your sh file executable (use the `chmod +x` command)

If it doesn't work properly, create a symlink of your file to `/etc/rc.d/`:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/test.sh /etc/rc.d/
```

May that helps :)

Comment: The question asks how to automatically detect change, not how to start on boot